# What is the functionality of namespaces in xml documents?

Tags: xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are XML namespaces for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128389/what-are-xml-namespaces-for)

xmlns attribute of the xml element!

Answer (score 0):

Just like the .NET namespaces, it is designed to allow you to clearly identify objects and avoid name conflicts.

E.g. you can have a `Person` in the `http://mycompany.com/schemas/Internal` XML namespace, and also another type `Person` in `http://mycompany.com/schemas/ERP` - and those two will not conflict on their name.

See this great article here [The XML Files - Understanding XML Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302166.aspx) which explains it in much greater detail and much better than I do.