# What does "m2" mean in XAML?

Tags: xaml

In in the Package.appxmanifest file in my Windows Store app I noticed it has:

```
<m2:VisualElements DisplayName="NameOfApp"/>
```

Does anyone know what the `m2` means?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are XML namespaces for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128389/what-are-xml-namespaces-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your manifest should be something similar to this...

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest">
```

The `m2` points to the namespace schema defined by the URL http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Answer (score 2):

`m2` is an xml namespace alias.

Specifically, `m2` is generally used to refer to extensions added to the 2013 version of the schema:

```
xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest"
```

To distinguish it from the version used as the default namespace:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest"
```

More on [VisualElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn423310.aspx) here.