# how to parse (this) xml using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing

I need to parse this [xml](http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_bas.cgi?ico=27074358&xml=1) by Google Script. jsonformatter.org tells me that the XML is valid

[image]

I want to get text of ICO but `//var ico = root.getChild('Ares_odpovedi').getChild('Odpoved').getChild('VBAS').getChild('ICO').getText();` is throwing an error

The full code is

```
function getARES() {
var url = 'https://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_bas.cgi?'
    + 'ico=06018025'
    + '&xml=1';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

var responseText = response.getContentText(); //.replace(/D:/g,'');

var document = XmlService.parse(responseText);
var root = document.getRootElement();

var ico_tmp0 = root.getName();                 // value is "Ares_odpovedi"
var ico_tmp1 = root.getContentSize();          // value is 3         
var ico_tmp2 = root.getChild('Ares_odpovedi'); // value is null
var ico_tmp3 = root.getChild('Odpoved');       // value is null
//var ico = root.getChild('Ares_odpovedi').getChild('Odpoved').getChild('VBAS').getChild('ICO').getText();
//var ico = root.getChild('Odpoved').getChild('VBAS').getChild('ICO').getText();

Logger.log(response);
Logger.log(" ");
Logger.log(responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the text of `ICO` using Google Apps Script.

In this case, it is required to use the name space when `getChild` is used. When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function getARES() {
  var url = 'https://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_bas.cgi?'
      + 'ico=06018025'
      + '&xml=1';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  var responseText = response.getContentText(); //.replace(/D:/g,'');

  var document = XmlService.parse(responseText);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  
  // I modified below script.
  var ns1 = XmlService.getNamespace("/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_answer_basic/v_1.0.3");
  var ns2 = XmlService.getNamespace("/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_datatypes/v_1.0.3");
  var res = root.getChild("Odpoved", ns1).getChild("VBAS", ns2).getChild("ICO", ns2).getText();
  Logger.log(res)
}
```

- When above script is run, `06018025` is retrieved.
- When `http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_bas.cgi?ico=27074358&xml=1` is used as the URL of `UrlFetchApp.fetch`, `27074358` is obtained.

#### References:

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)

### Added:

From your replying of `Any idea why var res2 = root.getChild("Odpoved", ns1).getChild("VBAS", ns2).getChild("DIC", ns2).getText(); does not work?`, now I noticed that your question had been changed.

In your question, you wanted to retrieve the value of `ICO`. But in the case for retrieving the value of `DIC`, it is required to check the structure of XML. Because in your script in your question, the XML from `var url = 'https://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_bas.cgi?' + 'ico=06018025' + '&xml=1';` doesn't include the value of `DIC`. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

When you want to retrieve the value of `DIC` from `http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_bas.cgi?ico=27074358&xml=1`, please use the following script.

#### Modified script:

```
function getARES() {
  var url = 'http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_bas.cgi?ico=27074358&xml=1';  // <--- Modified
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var responseText = response.getContentText(); //.replace(/D:/g,'');
  var document = XmlService.parse(responseText);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var ns1 = XmlService.getNamespace("/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_answer_basic/v_1.0.3");
  var ns2 = XmlService.getNamespace("/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_datatypes/v_1.0.3");
  var res = root.getChild("Odpoved", ns1).getChild("VBAS", ns2).getChild("DIC", ns2).getText();  // <--- Modified
  Logger.log(res)  // In this case, CZ27074358 is retrieved.
}
```

#### Note:

About the name space, these threads might be useful.

- [What are XML namespaces for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/128389)
- [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231)

Comment: hmm, so I did exactly what you except I did not use namespace. You said "in this case" namespace is required to use. Could you please explain why namespace must be use and why we have to use 2 different ones?

Comment: Any idea why `var res2 = root.getChild("Odpoved", ns1).getChild("VBAS", ns2).getChild("DIC", ns2).getText();` does not work?

Comment: @Radek Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that in your current issue for `var res2 = root.getChild("Odpoved", ns1).getChild("VBAS", ns2).getChild("DIC", ns2).getText();` might be to due to the URL for retrieving XML data. So I added one more sample script for your additional question. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: you answered my question with your first version of your answer. I usually accept the answer once I fully understood. Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: What is the best way to find out in the script whether a child got a value?

Comment: @Radek Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `What is the best way to find out in the script whether a child got a value?`, unfortunately, in the current stage, I have no clear answer for this. I apologize that I cannot resolve your all questions. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would like to study more and more. When I found the best way for achieving it, I would like to tell you.

Comment: I found that `var dic2 = root.getChild("Odpoved", ns_are).getChild("VBAS", ns_d).getChildText("DIC", ns_d); ` will not throw an error. In case the elemenet does not have a value the variable will be null.