# SoapCore Read Soap1.1

Tags: .net, xml, soap, asp.net-core-3.1, soapcore

I have followed mulitple examples online but cannot seem to get the below to work. For all examples the following request will work:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <Process xmlns="http://sample.namespace.com/service/2.19/">
            <!-- Optional -->
            <ActionARequest>
                <Id>"Test"</Id>
                <Name>"Test"</Name>
            </ActionARequest>
        </Process>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

However when I change this to have the soap tags it does not work.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <Process xmlns="http://sample.namespace.com/service/2.19/">
            <!-- Optional -->
            <ActionARequest>
                <Id>"Test"</Id>
                <Name>"Test"</Name>
            </ActionARequest>
        </Process>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there a particular setting I am missing?

Startup.cs:

```
var transportBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
            var textEncodingBinding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            var customBinding = new CustomBinding(transportBinding, textEncodingBinding);
            app.UseSoapEndpoint<ICallbackService>("/integration-service/v2_17/ActionA", customBinding, SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
```

Comment: Namespaces are important not their prefix, or their lack of. If it's already working, then what's wrong with the first example?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bogdan, we are taking over a service that already exists so need to replicate the current request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

should be:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

See also: [What are XML namespaces for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128389/what-are-xml-namespaces-for)