# Is it normal for pinging schemas.datacontract.org to result in a timeout error?

Tags: web-services, soap, ping, datacontract

I have a soap webservice (not made by me) that uses in the .svc file that describes that webservice urls like:

```
<President xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ Zuga.net">
```

Does pinging `schemas.datacontract.org` resulting in timeout explains the fact that calling the webservice results in a timeout?
Or is it normal if I can't ping `schemas.datacontract.org`?

Answer (score 0):

> is it normal if I can't ping schemas.datacontract.org?

Yes. If you ping it and it results in a timeout, that has nothing to do with how your web service runs.

Those are just XML Namespace identifiers. They need to be [valid URIs, or in this case URLs](https://danielmiessler.com/study/difference-between-uri-url/), but it's not mandatory for them to point anywhere.

So if `http://schemas.datacontract.org/...` doesn't go anywhere, or doesn't open a page, or doesn't respond to pings, then that's just fine. They are just identifiers.

See these resources for more details:

- [What are XML namespaces for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128389/what-are-xml-namespaces-for)
- [What is http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ ?](http://zuga.net/articles/cs-what-is-http-schemas-datacontract-org-2004-07/)
- [Data Contract Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-names)